# AR.js A-Frame click event

Tags: aframe, ar.js

The click event does not work for the whole 3D Model, it only works on the bottom of it.
Can you help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>AI TEST</title>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.4.0/aframe.min.js"></script>       
    <script src='https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js'></script>
</head>

<script>
AFRAME.registerComponent('cursor-listener', {
  init: function() {    
    var data = this.data;
    var el = this.el;
    el.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
      alert('click');
      console.log('click')
    });
  }
});
</script>

<body style="margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;">
    <a-scene cursor='rayOrigin: mouse; fuse: false' raycaster="objects: .clickable;"  vr-mode-ui='enabled: false'  arjs='sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: false' renderer='antialias: true; alpha: true; precision: medium'>
      
      <a-light type="ambient" color="#ffffff" intensity="50"></a-light>      
      <a-entity class="clickable" cursor-listener gltf-model="GoldCoin.gltf" scale="1 1 1" class="clickable" position="0 5 -10"></a-entity>
          

    </a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

The click event works only on the bottom of the 3D model, I want it to work everywhere.